# Replacing jittered dots with specific characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data are:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- read.table(text = " Family   Time1   Time2
AA1 12  11
AA2 13.5    12
AA3 11  12
AA4 12.5    11.5
AA5 13  14.5
AA6 17  16.5
AA7 21  22
AA8 19  18.5
AA9 14  13
AA10    8.5 8.2
AA11    12  13
AA12    17  16
AA13    14  12.5
AA14    11  12
AA15    16  17
AA16    13.5    14

", header = TRUE)
```

I want to replace jittered points with "M1" to "M16". For example at the end of the trend line (21,22), I want to see "M7" instead of "black dot". Including the black dots are ok. So for AA1 is "M1", for AA2 is "M2" and so on. I have used `scale_shape_manual`, but it did not work.

I have done:

```
gplot(df1,  aes(Time1 , Time2)) +
    geom_jitter()  +
    geom_smooth(level = 0.95, method = "loess") +
    scale_shape_manual(values=df1$family)+
    stat_cor(method = "spearman", label.sep = sprintf(", n = %s, ", nrow(df1))) +
    theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html) tells us that

> The jitter geom is a convenient shortcut for `geom_point(position = "jitter")`

So use that instead:

```
df1$Label = paste0('M', seq_len(nrow(df1)))

ggplot(df1,  aes(Time1 , Time2)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Label), position = 'jitter')  +
    geom_smooth(level = 0.95, method = "loess") +
    scale_shape_manual(values=df1$family)+
    stat_cor(method = "spearman", label.sep = sprintf(", n = %s, ", nrow(df1))) +
    theme_classic()
```

You might also be interested in the [ggrepel package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/index.html) which provides a more robust and visually appealing way of avoiding overlapping labels than jittering does.